# Dell Inspiron 5521 i7-3317U Fan CPU too Noisy

Tags: dell, fan

I am having a problem with the fan speed with my new Dell Inspiron 5521 i7-3317U, Full HD with installed Ubuntu 12.04. The fan is too noisy.

After starting the Laptop, the fan starts and is not stopping or changing the revolutions at all. Still I didn't install any Windows just because the Laptop is new. What should I do: return the Laptop or will updating the BIOS will solve the Problem? I saw that there is a newer version of the BIOS: AO7.

Comment: You also need to update the bios ...Download Ubuntu 13.04 x64, Make a boot usb, Use live session & check with it ....

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use **i8kutils**, a collection of utilities for Dell laptops. In this collection there is **i8kmon**, which is the utility I'm actually using right now.

## How To solve Dell laptops fan issues in Ubuntu

1. First of all, let's download and install i8kutils. Open your terminal and write:

`sudo apt-get install i8kutils`

2. Now you've got to add i8k to your modules. Open the modules file:

`sudo gedit /etc/modules`

and add the string "**i8k**" (without quotes) to the file. Save and exit.

3. Create an `i8k.conf` file

   `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf`

   and fill it with this code:

   `options i8k force=1`

Note: Some older guides will tell you to create a /modprobe.d/options file. The "options" file isn't used anymore on Ubuntu. What does matter is that you create a file with a .conf extension (the filename isn't important, but I decided to name it i8k.conf for clarity). So beware of older i8kmon configuration guides.

4. Now restart your computer, or run this code to make i8k run:

`sudo modprobe i8k force=1`

5. We will now create a i8kmon.conf file which will tell the i8kmon utility how to behave.

`sudo gedit /etc/i8kmon.conf`

Paste the following code in it:

```
    # Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
    set config(daemon)      0
     
    # Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
    set config(auto)        1
     
    # Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
    set config(verbose) 1
     
    # Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
    set config(timeout) 20
     
    # Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
    set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
    set config(1)   {{-1 1}  30  60  30  60}
    set config(2)   {{-1 2}  53  128  53  128}
     
    # For computer with 2 fans, use a variant of this instead:
    # Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
    # set config(0) {{-1 0}  -1  52  -1  65}
    # set config(1) {{-1 1}  41  66  55  75}
    # set config(2) {{-1 1}  55  80  65  85}
    # set config(3) {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}
     
    # end of file
```

This has been edited to match my Dell Inspiron 15r 5521 fan configuration (and I hope I did it well). If you want more informations take a look at the documentation on Ubuntu Manuals: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/i8kmon.1.html

6. Now you should be able to run **i8kmon** from your terminal and see if (and how) it's working. Simply run:

`i8kmon`

Finished!

---

**Sources:**

- [Keenformatics -  How to solve Dell laptops fan issues in Ubuntu](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in-ubuntu) (my blog)

Comment: Make sure that you really place the configuration file at `/etc/i8kmon.conf` instead of `/etc/default/i8kmon` which the i8kmon man page suggests. See my answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/717067/error-in-starting-i8kmon-service-when-setting-custom-config/761804#761804

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable powersaving for chipset and other devices:

`sudo apt-get install powertop`

`sudo powertop`

Go to "tunables" tab and change all "bad" items to "good"

All changes reset after reboot. And some of them change depending on AC/Battery mode.

So you also have to make powertop changes permanent
and disable pm-powersave scripts